# paypal - express checkout - transaction can't be finish

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm testing my code on the paypal sandbox and it works until now, BUT now when i complete the paypal part (login to approve the payement) i receive this message without any indication of what goes wrong.

[Error message in french](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3yoF.png)

Juste before the step, paypal display well all the information sent.

So, where can we found detail of the fail or anyone know this kind of problem ?

If it can help, here is the code based on the DPayPal PHP class

```
        $paypal = new DPayPal();
        $paypalConf = badawok::$config['paypal'];

        $paypal->setUsername($paypalConf['username']);
        $paypal->setPassword($paypalConf['password']);
        $paypal->setApiSignature($paypalConf['signature']);
        $paypal->setPayPalAPIUrl($paypalConf['url']);

        //$params = $this->getPaypalParams($port_fees);
        $requestParams = array(
            'RETURNURL' => SITEURL . "/" . t::url('basket') . '/ok/' . $paypalkey,
            'CANCELURL' => SITEURL . "/" . t::url('basket') . '/ko/' . $paypalkey,
            'LOCALECODE' => 'fr_FR'
        );
        //Order settings
        $orderParams = array(
            //'LOGOIMG' => "", //URL of your website logo. This image which will be displayed to the customer on the PayPal checkout page
            "MAXAMT" => "100", //Set maximum amount of transaction
            "NOSHIPPING" => "1", //I do not want shipping
            "ALLOWNOTE" => "0", //I do not want to allow notes
            "BRANDNAME" => "Loubilux sàrl",
            "GIFTRECEIPTENABLE" => "0", //Disable gift receipt widget on the PayPal pages
            "GIFTMESSAGEENABLE" => "0" //Disables the gift message widget on the PayPal pages
        );

        //Item settings
        $item = array(
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale'
        );

        //Add items
        $cmdconds = $this->getConds();
        $i = 0;
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($cmdconds as $c) {
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME' . $i] = $c['label'];
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' . $i] = $c['prix'];
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY' . $i] = $c['qte'];
            $total += $c['prixtot'];
            $i++;
        }
        //Fees
        if ($port_fees > 0) {
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME' . $i] = t::_('paypal_fees');
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' . $i] = $port_fees;
            $item['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY' . $i] = 1;
            $total += $port_fees;
            $i++;
        }
        //Total
        $item['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = $total;
        $item['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'] = $total;

        $params = $requestParams + $orderParams + $item;
        $response = $paypal->SetExpressCheckout($params);
```

This works until now, and the paypal part never call back my website. So there are an error on the paypal part but i don't know why.

Comment: It seem the problem disapear, maybe a temporary problem on the sandbox :s but no information.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 API's involved in completing a transaction.
SetExpresCheckout
GetExpressCheckout
DoExpressCheckout

Looks like you are calling just the SetExpressCheckout,
to complete a transaction we need all 3 API's

visit the following link for a sample code:

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php

Comment: Yes, thanks :), all of that is ok, i have my 3 steps.

My question is why paypal fail on his part when i log in to accept the pay. And how get help for this unhelfull error message.